# Auto-Notifications for new questions in Stack Overflow?

Tags: support, questions, answers, notifications

Is there a feature in **Stack Overflow** that would send us the new **questions** or **notifications** of the tags in ***Email*** or ***Desktop notifications***? That would really be cool and would ease out the task of every time checking for new questions and answers. It would save lot of time for both the person who has asked the question and the person who is answering it!

Answer (score 11):

I found out that we could configure email notifications in profile preferences, that would work for now, but desktop notifications would be good though!

Comment: For desktop notifications there's various userscripts, check http://stackapps.com/search?q=desktop+notifications, not sure if there's one which does notifications for tag pages though.